# Java Jsoup can't select table

Tags: java, web-scraping, web-crawler, jsoup

I have recently started to work on a mini project so I can learn the basis of Jsoup, however I have some difficulty to select a table on a particular website. I'm trying to fetch the table with Jsoup but with no sucess (see picture) https://i.stack.imgur.com/dkv7X.jpg

I know that the table that i'm trying to get have the class="meddelande" and is also inside a form element which have the same class="meddelande".
HTML code of the website: http://pastebin.com/ufRDhLSy

I'm trying to fetch the red marked area, any idea on how to do it?
Thanks in advance! :)

My code:

```
public void startMessage(String cookie1) {
    try {
        doc1 = Jsoup.connect("https://nya.boplats.se/minsida/meddelande")
                .timeout(0).cookie("Boplats-Session", cookie1)
                .get();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Elements tables = doc1.select("form.meddelande");
    Elements table = tables.select("table.meddelande");
    System.out.println(table);
}
```

Comment: Can we see your code?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/d10GpDpD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your situation better select class unread and read.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

public class JsoupSO {

    public static void main(String args0[]) throws IOException {
        Document doc;
        Elements elements;

        doc = Jsoup.parse(new File("path_to_file or use connect for URL"), "UTF-8");

        elements = doc.getElementsByClass("unread");
        for (Element element : elements) {
            System.out.println(element);
        }

        elements = doc.getElementsByClass("read");
        for (Element element : elements) {
            System.out.println(element);
        }
    }

}
```

Output: http://pastebin.com/CwG1cL5T

And yes read their cookbook http://jsoup.org/

Comment: it’s no bother, I glad that I can help someone ;-)

Answer (score 2):

In your code

```
Elements tables = doc1.select("form.meddelande");    
Elements table = tables.select("table.meddelande");
```

you are trying to access `form` with `class` attribute `meddelande` but from your linked HTML source `meddelande` is `id`, not `class`, so instead of

```
form.meddelande
```

you should use

```
form#meddelande
    ^--# means id, dot represents class
```

So try with

```
Elements tables = doc.select("form#meddelande");    
Elements table = doc.select("table.meddelande");
```

or maybe simpler

```
Elements table = doc.select("form#meddelande table.meddelande");
```

---

If this will not work then HTML code responsible for table is probably generated by JavaScript. In that case you will not be able to get it with Jsoup, but you will need something like [Selenium web driver](http://www.seleniumhq.org/projects/webdriver/), or [HtmlUtil](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an attempt

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=ufRDhLSy").get();
System.out.println(doc.select("table[class=meddelande]"));
```

or use the shorter syntax when selecting the node with a particular class only

```
System.out.println(doc.select("table.meddelande"));
```

JSoup supports the selector syntax. So you could use that to select DOM nodes with particular attributes - in this case the class attribute.

For more complex options in the selector syntax, look here http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax

Comment: Thanks for the book, didn't know about that one. Your code also helped! :D thank you